# Angular - Reactive Form selct inpout box- Dropdown options issue

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-reactive-forms

I have try to use reactive form group to create a formcontrol cosnit of input box and select tag ropdown value . But when i open the screen the dropdown box comes as empty, when i click on it it is getting filled with data.

I want to show place holder value when i open the screen and user can go to drop down and select the options value.

**HTML**

```
[formGroup]="selectieForm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="content-background">
            <div class="content">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="input">
                    <input type='text' placeholder="BRINNaam" formControlName="identificatieBrin" class="input_control input_control--text input_control--validate input_control--large">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Vestiging" formControlName="identificatieVestiging" class="input_control input_control--text input_control--validate input_control--large">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="inpu">
                    <select id="signalType"  class="input_control input_control--m  input_control--select" formControlName="identificatieSelectieSignals">
                      <option value="" disabled hidden>Choose Signal </option>
                      <option  *ngFor="let signal of signals" [value]="signal">{{signal.label}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2" >
                  <div class="input">
                    <select id="jaar" class="input_control input_control--m  input_control--select " formControlName="identificatieSelectieJaar">
                      <option value="" disabled hidden>Choose BeKostiging Jaar </option>
                      <option [value]="jaar" *ngFor="let jaar of jaren">{{jaar.label}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2" >
                  <div class="input">
                    <select class="input_control input_control--m  input_control--select" formControlName="identificatieSelectieSoort">
                      <option value="" disabled hidden>Choose Teldatum Soort </option>
                      <option [value]="type" *ngFor="let type of types">{{type.label}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
```

**Component.ts**

```
this.selectieForm = new FormGroup({
      identificatieBrin: new FormControl(""),
      identificatieVestiging: new FormControl(""),
      identificatieSelectieSignals: new FormControl(""),
      identificatieSelectieJaar: new FormControl(""),
      identificatieSelectieSoort: new FormControl("")
    });
```

[image]

**Picture**

When i select the drop down "choose signal or any "  it is empty when i deslsect it , then it get fill with data

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set the initial value of these dropdowns as undefined/null.

Something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  selectieForm: FormGroup;
  signals = [
    { label: 'Signal 1' },
    ...
  ];
  jaren = [
    { label: 'Jaren 1' },
    ...
  ];
  types = [
    { label: 'Type 1' },
    ...
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectieForm = new FormGroup({
      identificatieBrin: new FormControl(""),
      identificatieVestiging: new FormControl(""),

      // Something like this:
      identificatieSelectieSignals: new FormControl(),
      identificatieSelectieJaar: new FormControl(),
      identificatieSelectieSoort: new FormControl()
    });
  }

}
```

And then in your template, also specify the `value` of the Placeholder `option` tags as `null`, something like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="selectieForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="content-background">
        <div class="content">

          <div class="row">

           ...

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="inpu">
                <select id="signalType" class="input_control input_control--m  input_control--select" formControlName="identificatieSelectieSignals">
                  <option value="null" disabled hidden>Choose Signal </option>
                  <option *ngFor="let signal of signals" [value]="signal">{{signal.label}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="input">
                <select id="jaar" class="input_control input_control--m  input_control--select " formControlName="identificatieSelectieJaar">
                  <option value="null" disabled hidden>Choose BeKostiging Jaar </option>
                  <option [value]="jaar" *ngFor="let jaar of jaren">{{jaar.label}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="input">
                <select class="input_control input_control--m  input_control--select" formControlName="identificatieSelectieSoort">
                  <option value="null" disabled hidden>Choose Teldatum Soort </option>
                  <option [value]="type" *ngFor="let type of types">{{type.label}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m81v2x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: I want to keep "Choose signal" as a place holder .. when i select it shows allt he options values. I am not looking to get prefefined default values in dropdown

Comment: @AAMIRAZAM, fixed.

Comment: For me , its still not working .. its coming empty and after i click once ,its loading the data :(

Comment: @AAMIRAZAM, please fork my Sample StackBlitz, update it to replicate your issue and share the link to your StacBlitz here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the initial value first in your reactive form like the following way

> import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
>
> @Component({   selector: 'my-app',   ... }) export class AppComponent
>   implements OnInit {
>
> registerForm: FormGroup;
>
> constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
>
> ngOnInit() {
>       this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
>
> ```
>   firstname: '',
>   lastname: '',
>   address: this.formBuilder.group({
>     street: '',
>     zip: '',
>     city: ''
>   })
> });
> ```
>
> } 
>   }

. Please follow the article link below. it's really helpful to understand how you can handle data in your reactive form. I've gone through it properly and this clears my all doubt related to reactive form.

Here is the link below
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html.

Comment: I m still not able to get it.. can ypou give me demo example

Answer (score 0):

You can use selected attribute conditionally.Selected is true when the formcontrolname value is empty.Here is the example for 'choose signal'

```
<select id="signalType" class="input_control input_control--m  input_control--select" formControlName="identificatieSelectieSignals">
              <option [selected]="!selectieForm.value.identificatieSelectieSignals" value="null" hidden>Choose Signal </option>
              <option *ngFor="let signal of signals" [value]="signal">{{signal.label}}</option>
            </select>
```